# How to define constants in fish?

Tags: shell, fish

In sh:

```
readonly constant=value
```

How to do it in fish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define read-only variables (constants) in fish. Only certain built-in environmental variables are read-only.

These read-only variables are: `status`, `history`, `version`, `_`, `LINES`, `COLUMNS` and `PWD`. Only root can modify `HOME` and `USER`.